# Application of Jensen Inequality for lower bound

Tags: inequality, jensen-inequality

In [this work](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.03585) Jensen inequality is applied to turn Eq (11) to Eq. (12).

The essential part of Equation 11:

$L = \int q_{X_0}(x_{0})  log (\int q_{X_1,…,X_T | X_0}(x_1,…,x_T|x_{0})*C(x_1,…x_T)  d_{x_1},… d_{x_T}) dx_0$

Then Equation 12 states
$L \geq \int q_{X_0,...,X_T}(x_0,...,x_T)  log (C(x_1,…x_T))  d_{x_1},… d_{x_T}) dx_0$

Here $q$ denotes density functions for the corresponding random variables.

Simply applying Jensen on L results however in an upper bound. Can someone give me a hint how to prove the inequality.

Comment: Hint: is $\log$ convex or concave?

Comment: OK, true, since log is concave, I obtain a lower bound. Still, I will have "log(q (x_1,...,x_T | x0) * C)" and I need "q (x_1,...,x_T | x0) * log(C)" to end up with the inequality provided.

Answer (score 1):

This paper is hard to understand. Still, I am going to use its notation:
\begin{align}\tag{9}
p\big(x^{(0)}\big)=\int d\mathbf{x}^{(1...T)}\,q\big(x^{(1...T)}\big|x^{(0)}\big)\,p\big(x^{(T)}\big)\prod_{t=1}^T\frac{p\big(x^{(t-1)}\big|x^{(t)}\big)}{q\big(x^{(t)}\big|x^{(t-1)}\big)}\,.
\end{align}
Presumably the authors integrate here over a cube $[a,b]^T\,.$ Applying Jensen's inequality to

- the finite measure $d\mu=d\mathbf{x}^{(1...T)}\,q\big(x^{(1...T)}\big|x^{(0)}\big)$ on $[a,b]^T$ and to
- the concave function log

yields
\begin{align}\tag{*}
\log p\big(x^{(0)}\big)\ge\int d\mathbf{x}^{(1...T)}\,q\big(x^{(1...T)}\big|x^{(0)}\big)\,\log\Bigg(p\big(x^{(T)}\big)\prod_{t=1}^T\frac{p\big(x^{(t-1)}\big|x^{(t)}\big)}{q\big(x^{(t)}\big|x^{(t-1)}\big)}\Bigg)\,.
\end{align}
I think the rest leading to (12) follows from
$$\tag{**}
\int d\mathbf{x}^{(0)}\,q\big(x^{(0)}\big)\int d\mathbf{x}^{(1...T)}\,q\big(x^{(1...T)}\big|x^{(0)}\big)f\big(\mathbf{x}^{(0...T)}\big)=\int d\mathbf{x}^{(0...T)}\,q\big(x^{(0...T)}\big)f\big(\mathbf{x}^{(0...T)}\big)
$$
which should hold for any function $f$. In your case $f$ it is the log of that huge expression in (*).

- Unfortunately, the authors don't seem to define $q\big(x^{(1...T)}\big|x^{(0)}\big)$ somewhere.

***Edit.***

The authors write
\begin{align}\tag{10}
L&=\int d\mathbf{x}^{(0)}\,q\big(\mathbf{x}^{(0)}\big)\,\log p\big(\mathbf{x}^{(0)}\big)\,.
\end{align}
Using (*) and (**) this is larger than
$$
\int d\mathbf{x}^{(0...T)}\,q\big(x^{(0...T)}\big)f\big(\mathbf{x}^{(0...T)}\big)
$$
where
$$
f\big(\mathbf{x}^{(0...T)}\big)=\log\Bigg(p\big(x^{(T)}\big)\prod_{t=1}^T\frac{p\big(x^{(t-1)}\big|x^{(t)}\big)}{q\big(x^{(t)}\big|x^{(t-1)}\big)}\Bigg)\,.
$$
In other words, the author's inequality (12) holds.

Comment: So my remaining question is still how to get rid of the logarithm: ((0))≥∫[((1...)|(0))∗((0...))] (1...) 
 (Jensen). How do you get now to your inequality (*)?

Comment: If [((1...)|(0))∗((0...))] = ((1...)|(0)) [((0...))], I would be clear for me. However this does not hold in general..

Comment: We don't need that. See edit.